# Which user executes Postgres RLS policies (CURRENT_USER vs VIEW owner)?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, row-level-security

Postgres seems to have some weird semantics around which user is actually invoking check functions defined in RLS policies. Specifically, if the check function is `SECURITY INVOKER`, it appears that the function permissions are applied with respect to `CURRENT_USER`, irrespective of whether the policy applies to a different user (as might be the case if the query goes via a view with a different owner). If the check function is `SECURITY DEFINER`, it appears that the functions are executed by the *policy* user.

First, some context:

- I have a database that uses RLS to gate access to data (PG v13, if that's relevant).
- There is a `main` schema which holds all the underlying data.
- There is an `api` schema, which holds views over the underlying data. In the simplest case, these views are just pass-thrus (e.g. `CREATE VIEW api.stuff AS SELECT a, b, c FROM main.stuff)
- Objects in the `api` schema are owned by an `api_owner` user
- The client that accesses the API is `api_user`, which is granted access to these views via `GRANT`
- RLS policies on tables in the `main` schema apply to `api_owner`, because `api_owner` owns the views that allow access to data stored on `main`
- RLS policies typically involve a check function, e.g. `CREATE POLICY api_owner_select ON main.stuff FOR SELECT TO api_owner USING (main.current_user_id() = user_id);`.

So, data access from a client's perspective looks something like the following:

```
[Client]    
GET /stuff 
    ↓
api_user (current_user)
SELECT * FROM api.stuff
    ↓
api_owner (policy user, via api.stuff query)
SELECT * FROM main.stuff
    ↓
Process query:
  - Check RLS policies on main.stuff that apply to api_owner
    - e.g. USING (main.current_user_id() = user_id)
    - filter rows that don't pass
  - Return resulting rows to client ⤴
```

So far, so good. However, the security status of the check function behaves very unintuitively:

- If the check function (`main.current_user_id()` in my examples above) is `SECURITY DEFINER`, everything works as expected. In particular, there is no issue with being able to call `main.current_user_id()`. I *assume* this is because `api_owner` has `USAGE` on the `main` schema, the policies apply to `api_owner`, and therefore the function is executed by `api_owner`.
- However, if the check function is `SECURITY INVOKER`, then I get the following error:

  ```
   ERROR:  permission denied for schema main
   LINE 3:   FROM main.users
                  ^
   QUERY:
     SELECT id
     FROM main.users
     WHERE users.email = current_setting('some_injected_state.email')
  ```

  The query here is from the internals of the `current_user_id()`.

This leads to a bit of a paradox:

- If the policy is being executed as the user accessing the data (i.e. `api_owner` via the view), then why should there be any issue? `api_owner` *does* have permission to access the `main` schema (and indeed has `SELECT` access on the `users` table), so the query should execute fine.
- If the policy is instead being executed as `CURRENT_USER` (i.e. `api_user`), then why does setting the policy to `SECURITY DEFINER` work? `api_user` doesn't have direct access to `main`, so I *would* expect an issue with accessing objects (including functions) on the schema.

  - Indeed, if I `SET ROLE api_user` and try to call `main.current_user_id()`, I get exactly the error I expect:

    ```
    my_db=# ALTER FUNCTION main.current_user_id SECURITY DEFINER;
    ALTER FUNCTION
    my_db=> SET ROLE api_user;
    SET
    my_db=> SELECT main.current_user_id();
    ERROR:  permission denied for schema main
    LINE 1: SELECT main.current_user_id();
    ```

So, can anyone shed any light on the rules that determine which user Postgres RLS policies are executed as?

Comment: If `current_user_id()` belongs to the owner of schema `main`. that would explain the behavior.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yeah, `current_user_id()` does indeed belong to the owner of `main`. Sorry if I'm being a bit thick here, but I guess I still don't see how that explains the (to my mind) paradoxical behaviour of how the policies appear to be executed. In particular, making the function `SECURITY DEFINER` appears to not only allow the body of the function to be executed with elevated permissions, but also bypasses the need for a `GRANT` on the function, which is very counterintuitive (and, I'm sure, an incorrect explanation of what's happening).

Comment: From the error message, the problem is not that the function cannot be called (it *is* called), but that the function tries to select from a table in a schema where the invoker (the user querying the data) has no access. With `SECURITY DEFINER`, the function is running with the security context of the owner of `main`, so the SQL statements in the function have no problem accessing tables in `main`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is it correct then that you don't need `USAGE` on `main` to call functions there, only query tables?

Comment: it seems to me that there are essentially two mysteries here: one, that you can call a function on `main`, which can then in its execution fail because you don't have permission to access objects on `main`; two, that you end up using an RLS policy specified for `api_owner`, but seemingly the code does not execute with the permissions of `api_owner`. The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-rowsecurity.html#:~:text=Policy%20expressions%20are%20run%20as%20part%20of%20the%20query%20and%20with%20the%20privileges%20of%20the%20user%20running%20the%20query) don't seem explicit about this.

Comment: I know that is confusing. You have to distinguish between 1) permission checks on the function and 2) executing the function. When you are using a view (that doesn't have `security_invoker = on`), the permissions to execute the function are checked *for the owner of the view*, but the function is called in the context of the user *who runs the query* (unless you have `SECURITY DEFINER`).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think this is probably the root of my confusion: "but the function is called in the context of the user who runs the query" – isn't this also the owner of the view?

Comment: No, the view owner is just used to check the permissions on the objects used in the view (and to determine the RLS policies that apply). But the function runs with with the user who did the `SELECT`. Even if that user does not have permissions to execute the function.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe first of all, thanks so much for the info so far, it's really appreciated. Sorry to keep at this, but I still feel like something here doesn't make sense. Based on what you've said, GRANTs (and which user RLS policies are applied to) are evaluated with respect to the view owner, but function execution (in the context of RLS) is evaluated as `CURRENT_USER`. But if I call a `SECURITY DEFINER` function (in any context), functions inside it are called in the context of the outer function's owner. Why is this different for a view (which is analogous to a `SECURITY DEFINER` function)?

Comment: Oh no, a "why" question. Views and functions are different things. Functions can be executed, views cannot. With a sufficiently complex setup like yours (which I didn't fully understand, which is the reason why I couldn't write a comprehensive answer), you can easily end up with non-intuitive behavior.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe fair enough, thanks again for all the info you were able to provide!